# How do I apply a function using comparisons of data in two or more columns with R data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to apply a function to an R data table object that compares values in two columns and returns a result. Here's the example, for data table X:

```
X <- as.data.table(list(POSITION=c(1,4,5,9,24,36,42,56),
   FIRST=c("A","BB","AA","B","AAA","B","A,B"),
   SECOND=c("B","AA","B","AAA","BBB","AB,ABB","B,A")))

   POSITION FIRST SECOND
1:        1     A      B
2:        4    BB     AA
3:        5    AA      B
4:        9     B    AAA
5:       24   AAA    BBB
6:       36     B AB,ABB
7:       42   A,B    B,A
8:       56     A      B
```

I would like to perform the following logical comparisons of the data in columns "FIRST" and "SECOND", to create a "RESULT" column:

```
 SAME = length of FIRST and SECOND are both one character
 BLOCK = Character length of FIRST and SECOND are the same,
         but greater than one, and not mixed (i.e. no comma)
 LESS = SECOND has fewer characters, but neither is mixed
 MORE = SECOND has more characters, but neither is mixed
 MIXED = either firs of second contains a comma
```

Thus, the desired result would look like:

```
POSITION FIRST SECOND RESULTS
1        A     B      SAME
4        BB    AA     BLOCK
5        A     B,A    MIXED    
9        AA    B      LESS
24       B     AAA    MORE
28       BBB   A,B    MIXED
36       AAA   BBB    BLOCK
42       B     AB,ABB MIXED
56       A,B   B,A    MIXED
```

So the following works, but is slow over a file with 4 million rows!

```
X[, RESULT := ifelse(nchar(FIRST)+nchar(SECOND)==2,"SAME",
    ifelse(grepl(",", FIRST) | grepl(",",SECOND), "MIXED",
       ifelse(nchar(FIRST) > nchar(SECOND), "LESS",
          ifelse(nchar(FIRST) < nchar(SECOND), "MORE","BLOCK")))]
```

But it does give thew desired result:

```
   POSITION FIRST SECOND RESULT
1:        1     A      B   SAME
2:        4    BB     AA  BLOCK
3:        5    AA      B   LESS
4:        9     B    AAA   MORE
5:       24   AAA    BBB  BLOCK
6:       36     B AB,ABB  MIXED
7:       42   A,B    B,A  MIXED
8:       56     A      B   SAME
```

I actually have several more conditions to test, and some of them get more complicated that just character counts. Rather than a long ifelse statement, is it possible to apply a function, taking the two columns as input? For example:

```
checkType <- function(x) {
  if(nchar(x$FIRST)+nchar(x$SECOND)==2) {
    type <- "SNP"
  } else if(!grepl(",", x$SECOND) & !grepl(",",x$FIRST) & (nchar(x$FIRST) > nchar(x$SECOND))) {
    type <- "LESS"
  } else if(!grepl(",", x$SECOND) & !grepl(",",x$FIRST) & (nchar(x$FIRST) < nchar(x$SECOND))) {
    type <- "MORE"
  } else if (!grepl(",", x$SECOND) & !grepl(",",x$FIRST) & (nchar(x$FIRST) == nchar(x$SECOND)) & nchar(x$SECOND)>1) {
    type <-"BLOCK"
  } else {
    type <- "MIXED"
  }
  return(type)
}

> checkType(X[1,])
[1] "SAME"

for(i in 1:nrow(X)) X[i, RESULT := checkType(X[i,])]
```

So while the above works, it's obviously not the optimal way to run things with data.table. However, I tried lapply and apply, but neither work:

```
X[, RESULT3 := lapply(.SD, checkType)]
 Error in x$FIRST : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors 
  nchar(x$FIRST) 
  FUN(X[[1L]], ...) 
  lapply(.SD, checkType) 
  eval(expr, envir, enclos) 
  eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) 
  `[.data.table`(X, , `:=`(RESULT3, lapply(.SD, checkType))) 
  X[, `:=`(RESULT3, lapply(.SD, checkType))]
```

Same result with apply(.SD, 1, checkType). Is what I am trying to do possible by applying a function?

Comment: I'm guessing that if you did it in steps and avoided `ifelse` altogether it'd be faster - i.e. `X[nchar(FIRST)+nchar(SECOND)==2, RESULT := "SAME"]; X[grepl(",", FIRST) | grepl(",",SECOND), RESULT := "MIXED"]; ...`

Comment: You probably shouldn't do it (because it's slow), but one way to use that function would be `X[,RESULT3:=checkType(.SD),by=1:nrow(X)]`

Comment: This worked (unlike apply or lapply), but was 40 times slower than your answer below. I guess that using apply or lapply when comparing values in a subset of columns is not possible. Certainly, you can apply functions like "sum" on a subset of columns, but to have a list of conditions to apply to X$Col1 & X$Col2 and return different results accordingly, can't be done using 'lapply' or 'apply'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So both the answers from @Frank and @jlhoward give the desired result, and were much quicker than my initial attempt. From these answers however, this approach (createResult1) was about 4 times faster over a file with 1,000,000 rows:

```
createResult1 <- function(X) {
  X[,`:=`(
    cf=nchar(FIRST),
    cs=nchar(SECOND),
    mf=grepl(',',FIRST),
    ms=grepl(',',SECOND)
    )]
  X[cf==1&cs==1, RESULT:="SAME"]
  X[cf > cs, RESULT:="LESS"]
  X[cf < cs, RESULT:="MORE"]
  X[cf==cs & cs>1, RESULT:="BLOCK"]
  X[(mf)|(ms), RESULT:="MIXED"]
  X[,c('cf','cs','mf','ms'):=NULL]
  return(X)
}

createResult2 <- function(X) { #@Frank
  X[,`:=`(
    cf=nchar(FIRST),
    cs=nchar(SECOND),
    mf=grepl(',',FIRST),
    ms=grepl(',',SECOND)
  )][,RESULT:=ifelse(cf==1&cs==1,"SAME",
                     ifelse(mf | ms, "MIXED",
                            ifelse(cf > cs, "LESS",
                                   ifelse(cf < cs, "MORE","BLOCK"))))
     ][
       ,c('cf','cs','mf','ms'):=NULL
        ]
  return(X)
}

createResult3 <- function(X) { #@jlhoward
  X$mixed <- grepl(',',X$FIRST) | grepl(',',X$SECOND)
  X$nf    <- nchar(X$FIRST)
  X$ns    <- nchar(X$SECOND)
  X$RESULT = ""

  setkey(X,nf,ns)
  X[J(1,1),RESULT:="SAME"]
  X[!mixed & nf==ns & nf>1 & ns>1]$RESULT <- "BLOCK"
  X[!mixed & nf > ns]$RESULT <- "LESS"
  X[!mixed & nf < ns]$RESULT <- "MORE"
  X[(mixed)]$RESULT <- "MIXED"
  X[,c('nf','ns','mixed'):=NULL]
  setkey(X,POSITION)
  return(X)
}
```

Create the same data table as above, but with 1,000,000 rows

```
X <- as.data.table(list(POSITION=rep(c(1,4,5,9,24,36,42,56),1000000),
                        FIRST=rep(c("A","BB","AA","B","AAA","B","A,B"),1000000),
                        SECOND=rep(c("B","AA","B","AAA","BBB","AB,ABB","B,A"),1000000)))
Y <- copy(X)
Z <- copy(X)
```

Here are the results:

```
> system.time(X <- createResult1(X))
   user  system elapsed 
   4.06    0.05    4.12
> system.time(Y <- createResult2(Y))
   user  system elapsed 
  18.53    0.36   18.94 
> system.time(Z <- createResult2(Z))
   user  system elapsed 
  18.63    0.29   18.97 
> identical(X,Y)
[1] TRUE
> identical(X,Z)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Good stuff, though somehow I only got around to looking at it now. One small thing anyone who sees this Q&A might note: `createResult2` is used twice in the answer's benchmarking (instead of also using `createResult3`), but you can run the correct code on your own computer if interested: `system.time(Z <- createResult3(Z))`.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the data table produced by your code (first line below, pasted from your snippet above), is **not the same** as the data table shown in the "desired results" box below it.

Nevertheless, this might actually be faster, and would definitely be easier to understand. It produces a result which I think is consistent with your rules.

```
X <- as.data.table(list(POSITION=c(1,4,5,9,24,36,42,56),
                        FIRST=c("A","BB","AA","B","AAA","B","A,B"),
                        SECOND=c("B","AA","B","AAA","BBB","AB,ABB","B,A")))

X$mixed <- grepl(',',X$FIRST) | grepl(',',X$SECOND)
X$nf    <- nchar(X$FIRST)
X$ns    <- nchar(X$SECOND)
X$RESULT = ""

setkey(X,nf,ns)
X[J(1,1),RESULT:="SAME"]
X[!mixed & nf==ns & nf>1 & ns>1]$RESULT <- "BLOCK"
X[!mixed & nf > ns]$RESULT <- "LESS"
X[!mixed & nf < ns]$RESULT <- "MORE"
X[(mixed)]$RESULT <- "MIXED"
setkey(X,POSITION)
```

Your categories are not mutually exclusive, so I assume these rules apply in order (for example what about `FIRST=","` and `SECOND=","`?

Also, I think your definitions of MORE and LESS are the same.

Comment: Yeah, the use of `ifelse` suggests that the rules should be applied in order, I reckon. For speed's sake, I think something like `X[result==""][new_condition,result:=new_code]` at each step would be good, since it prevents you from computing the vector of conditions (!mixed and whatever else) for all the rows. Assigning with `<-` to a data.table is discouraged; see the introductory stuff that comes with the package, and be prepared for downvotes (though not from me) if you leave it in.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your suggestion but it is not working on the X[J(1,1)]$RESULTS <- "SAME" part: It throws lots of warnings and introduces NAs.

Comment: Hmm, okay, I just tried running this code, too, and it looks like it was not tested...so -1 until it works. The last line certainly should not run.